# How to add an add desktop shortcut button in my website?

Tags: html, shortcut-file

You know how you save a website into your computer using a desktop shortcut, right? You need to go to the menu then click "More Tools" then click "Create Shortcut". I want to save my users the hassle and add a button which does the same thing. How exactly do I do this? Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your website to a PWA. PWA's enable to browser to prompt the user to save the website as an app on their device, and run it directly from their device without have to visit the browser.

This will require you to add a `manifest.json` and a `service worker` on your website to be able to convert to a PWA.

To enable users to be able to save your PWA, you need to listen to `beforeinstallprompt` event, save the event, and re-fire the prompt on the button click that you want to trigger the installation.

More details on PWA and service workers :

1. PWA : https://web.dev/progressive-web-apps/
2. Service worker : https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers
3. Deferred PWA installation : https://web.dev/customize-install/

Comment: I'm using github in hosting my website. Will this work? Do I just need to add the file? And what code will I use?

Comment: @G1blue Github hosting should be fine. Service workers need `https` URL to work on. You can probably. go through the links above to get some understanding of how to enable and serve service workers. In summary, you need to create 2 new files, one `manifest.json` and one `serviceworker.js`. Serve both of them from your `index.html`. Serviceworker offers lot of capabilities like caching, intercepting network requests and lot more.